# Http Status 404 after installing Tomcat 9

Tags: tomcat

I downloaded and unzip Tomcat im my home directory, then configured Tomcat in Eclipse and started the instance from the Servers tab. When I try and open localhost:8080, I get an Http Status 404 error with this message: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists. Why is the default application not loading?

```
Jan 10, 2019 7:55:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.14
Jan 10, 2019 7:55:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Dec 6 2018 21:13:53 UTC
Jan 10, 2019 7:55:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 9.0.14.0
Jan 10, 2019 7:55:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
Jan 10, 2019 7:55:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
Jan 10, 2019 7:55:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Jan 10, 2019 7:55:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1
Jan 10, 2019 7:55:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           11.0.1+13-LTS
Jan 10, 2019 7:55:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Jan 10, 2019 7:55:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\hendre\Documents\FileSystem\Lot 24 Media\Eclipse Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Jan 10, 2019 7:55:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\hendre\apache-tomcat-9.0.14
Jan 10, 2019 7:55:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\hendre\Documents\FileSystem\Lot 24 Media\Eclipse Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Jan 10, 2019 7:55:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\hendre\apache-tomcat-9.0.14
Jan 10, 2019 7:55:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\hendre\Documents\FileSystem\Lot 24 Media\Eclipse Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Jan 10, 2019 7:55:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Jan 10, 2019 7:55:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.19] using APR version [1.6.5].
Jan 10, 2019 7:55:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Jan 10, 2019 7:55:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
Jan 10, 2019 7:55:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018]
Jan 10, 2019 7:55:46 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jan 10, 2019 7:55:48 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jan 10, 2019 7:55:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Server initialization in [12,250] milliseconds
Jan 10, 2019 7:55:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Jan 10, 2019 7:55:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.14]
Jan 10, 2019 7:55:49 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jan 10, 2019 7:55:49 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jan 10, 2019 7:55:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [1,164] milliseconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Default Eclispe configures the `Server Location` of a new Tomcat instance to `Use workspace metadata`.
You'll find that folder in your workspace under folder `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0`

Therein you'll find a folder named `webapps` which is empty. Hence there is no app deployed at all and Tomcat can only spit out 404 response to any HTTP request.

You can copy applications from you downloaded apache-tomcat.zip/webapps folder into your Eclipse webapps folder which is in your case:
`C:\Users\hendre\Documents\FileSystem\Lot 24 Media\Eclipse Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\webapps`

Alternatively you can switch `Server Location` setting to `Use Tomcat Installation`.

BTW:
If you develop and add a web application from within Eclipse to the Tomcat instance this will be deployed to wtpwebapps - in your case:
`C:\Users\hendre\Documents\FileSystem\Lot 24 Media\Eclipse Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps`